# How to move the characters separated by comma in a cell into different rows in a data frame using R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

```
         Sample    chr        pos_s       pos_e     ref                           alt
        1800753    chr1     9770690     9770694   CAGAG                 C,CAG,CAGAGAG   
        1800532    chr1    45266875    45266877     CTT        C,CT,CTTT,CTTTT,CTTTTT    
        1800671    chr1    45266875    45266878    CTTT         C,CT,CTT,CTTTT,CTTTTT    
        1800563    chr1    45266875    45266878    CTTT    C,CT,CTT,TTTT,CTTTT,CTTTTT
```

Here is a dataframe, in which the alt column contains the charaters separated by comma. I want to move these characters into different rows and keep the rest columns. Here is an example

```
     Sample    chr        pos_s       pos_e     ref                           alt
    1800753    chr1     9770690     9770694   CAGAG                             C   
    1800753    chr1     9770690     9770694   CAGAG                           CAG
    1800753    chr1     9770690     9770694   CAGAG                       CAGAGAG
    1800532    chr1    45266875    45266877     CTT                             C
    1800532    chr1    45266875    45266877     CTT                            CT
    1800532    chr1    45266875    45266877     CTT                          CTTT
    1800532    chr1    45266875    45266877     CTT                         CTTTT
    1800532    chr1    45266875    45266877     CTT                        CTTTTT
    1800671    chr1    45266875    45266878    CTTT                             C
    1800671    chr1    45266875    45266878    CTTT                            CT
    1800671    chr1    45266875    45266878    CTTT                           CTT
    1800671    chr1    45266875    45266878    CTTT                         CTTTT
    1800671    chr1    45266875    45266878    CTTT                        CTTTTT
    1800563    chr1    45266875    45266878    CTTT                             C
    1800563    chr1    45266875    45266878    CTTT                            CT   
    1800563    chr1    45266875    45266878    CTTT                           CTT
    1800563    chr1    45266875    45266878    CTTT                          TTTT
    1800563    chr1    45266875    45266878    CTTT                         CTTTT
    1800563    chr1    45266875    45266878    CTTT                        CTTTTT
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
library( tidyverse )
df %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows( alt )

#    Sample chr      pos_s    pos_e ref   alt    
#     <int> <chr>    <int>    <int> <chr> <chr>  
# 1 1800753 chr1   9770690  9770694 CAGAG C      
# 2 1800753 chr1   9770690  9770694 CAGAG CAG    
# 3 1800753 chr1   9770690  9770694 CAGAG CAGAGAG
# 4 1800532 chr1  45266875 45266877 CTT   C      
# 5 1800532 chr1  45266875 45266877 CTT   CT     
# 6 1800532 chr1  45266875 45266877 CTT   CTTT   
# 7 1800532 chr1  45266875 45266877 CTT   CTTTT  
# 8 1800532 chr1  45266875 45266877 CTT   CTTTTT 
# 9 1800671 chr1  45266875 45266878 CTTT  C      
#10 1800671 chr1  45266875 45266878 CTTT  CT     
#11 1800671 chr1  45266875 45266878 CTTT  CTT    
#12 1800671 chr1  45266875 45266878 CTTT  CTTTT  
#13 1800671 chr1  45266875 45266878 CTTT  CTTTTT 
#14 1800563 chr1  45266875 45266878 CTTT  C      
#15 1800563 chr1  45266875 45266878 CTTT  CT     
#16 1800563 chr1  45266875 45266878 CTTT  CTT    
#17 1800563 chr1  45266875 45266878 CTTT  TTTT   
#18 1800563 chr1  45266875 45266878 CTTT  CTTTT  
#19 1800563 chr1  45266875 45266878 CTTT  CTTTTT
```